# Play 2.0 password field constructor: no value attrib?

Tags: forms, security, scala, playframework-2.0

Not sure if this is a security feature, an oversight, or me missing the ocean for the waves, but wondering why there is no value attribute for the [password field constructor](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputPassword.scala.html)

This is not an issue for user signup and other form creation events, but becomes a headache when, for example, a user renewal form does not have the password field filled in (and thus fails validation, which is ironic given that they just logged in in order to be able to renew in the first place ;-))

My workaround has been to set the value attrib manually by supplying it as an extra argument:

```
@inputPassword(
  _form("password"), '_label-> "Password*", 'class-> "required", 
  'value-> _form("password").value map{Some(_)} getOrElse Some("")
)
```

would prefer the value attribute included by default, however, as with other input elements. Yes, I can override it, but wondering what the dealy-O is regardless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, you shouldn't be able to retrieve the user password in any way, since the password should be encrypted before storing it somewhere.

Comment: +1, good point, but it's already encrypted. I just need the value for client + server-side validation to pass -- I don't update the password on renewal, but I do use the exact same form template as signup (keeping it DRY) -- the difference being that I jquery hide the password + label div container on renewal. Could probably take a different approach, just not too thrilled to maintain different form templates for screens that are empty/filled versions of the same thing

Comment: Ok, I better understand your concern. But transmiting the password between server and client too often is a bit "risky" ;-) So I think, for security matter, that you could be less DRY for this one ;-)

Comment: just saw this commit: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/c15a07684ef78e771b71e594b86e39a51fd3b95f, so it was intentional on Play dev team's part

Comment: since I am not updating the password on renewal, but rather hiding it (so validation passes), I am now just entering a dummy strong password into the hidden field (never gets persisted). If a hacker sniffs the dummy password, great, enjoy...the silence ;-)